# SSH logged in as different users on same host

Tags: git, ssh

I have 2 BitBucket accounts with different keys.
Here is my ~/.ssh/config

```
Host company.bitbucket.org
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User company
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company

Host personal.bitbucket.org
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User personal
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
```

In my repos:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = company@bitbucket.org:companyworkspace/project1.git
[remote "origin"]
    url = personal@bitbucket.org:personal/project2.git
```

When I use **git fetch** on each repository, sometime it connects correct, sometime it returns Forbidden.

After debugging, I consider a weird thing.

```
$ ssh -T company@bitbucket.org 
logged in as personal

$ ssh -T company@bitbucket.org 
logged in as company

$ ssh -T company@bitbucket.org 
logged in as personal

$ ssh -T somethingwrong@bitbucket.org 
logged in as personal
```

Could someone please explain why it is happening?

**UPDATED:**
I misunderstood that I configured ssh correctly, because I am still able to connect git well. The question is about weird behavior when git choose wrong key.
However finally, I considered the domain in .git/config must be same the Host in .ssh/config.

```
Host company.bitbucket // This line should be same git config [...@company.bitbucket:...]
      HostName bitbucket.org
      User company
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [push using multiple account / multiple identity on github / bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725033/push-using-multiple-account-multiple-identity-on-github-bitbucket)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bssh%5D+multiple+accounts

Comment: @phd I misunderstood about the configuration and thought it's different case with above link.

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit your git config

```
[remote "origin"]
url = git@personal.bitbucket.org:personal/repo.git
```

and for the other one replace the user and URL to Company.

at the end add this to your ssh config:

```
IdentitiesOnly=yes
```

Comment: I just updated my question. I have already had git remote config as above. I am still able to fetch code from Bitbucket. However sometime it returns Forbidden because of different user.

I just added "IdentitiesOnly yes" to each host config as your recommend but it still returns Forbidden:
`Host company.bitbucket.org
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User company
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company`

Comment: you need to use `personal.bitbucket.org` as a host in git config not bitbucket.org